# How to move the steps from one Load jobs to other in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to move some of the steps from one load job to another load job from SQL Server Agent.

Basically while moving,the steps from first load job must be deleted and inserted as the new steps in another load job.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that right click on your job in SSMS and select `Script job as\create` menu item and then change `@jobId` parameter in idea part of created script and run your script.